Cannot restore LineageOS launcher3/trebuchet from backup
I back up my phone by backing up the various state directories under /data/, including the /data/data/ state directory of the launcher. The details aren't important but the backups include all files' metadata, including xattrs and acls. Caches and certain ephemeral or otherwise replaceable files are excluded but for Trebuchet this only affects its cache directory.
When I back up, wipe and restore on Android 14 (LineageOS 21) however, the launcher is still in its default/reset state eventhough the launcher was modified when the backup was taken. This did not use to happen on Android 13 (LineageOS 20).
When I selectively restore the launcher's /data/data/ directory, it is still in the default state.
If I produce some launcher state and move all files under the launcher's /data/data/ directory, it resets as expected. If I then undo the rename, I get back to the state I initially produced.
What is going on? Where else could it be hiding state that is critical to the launcher function?
For reference, these are the state directories under /data that I generally restore:
/app/
/data/
/system/package*
/system/netpolicy.xml
/system/users/0/
/misc_de/0/apexdata/com.android.permission/
/user_de/0/
/misc/apexdata/com.android.wifi
/system/notification_policy.xml
/property/persistent_properties
/user_de/0/org.lineageos.lineagesettings
/misc/profiles/
/system_ce/


As it turns out, deleting the directory and then restoring it again did the trick and the data was restored successfully.
Perhaps one should generally wipe /data/data/ before restoring a backup as system apps will already have run once and may populate e.g. caches with data that doesn't work with the restored data.
